# Spanish Dvorak Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, dvorak

Actually i am learning to write with the Dvorak Keyboard. In the system configuration for Language and Text i have three Dvorak options (Left, Right and Querty) but none for spanish (with 'ñ' and accents).

There are a way to configure Dvorak for spanish ?

Comment: If you hold a key down (like n) you should get a popup menu with accented versions (like ñ).  Also the usual option deadkeys (option n, then n) should work.

Comment: that is a very nice solution, but it means that is the only solution for the spanish keyboard?

Comment: Perhaps if you search google you can find someone who has made a custom dvorak keyboard for Spanish.  The usual way to do that is with the app Ukelele.  http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

Answer (score 2):

If you hold a key down (like n) you should get a popup menu with accented versions (like ñ). Also the usual option deadkeys (option n, then n) should work.

An example of a custom layout someone has made for this is at

http://djelibeibi.unex.es/dvorak/

http://djelibeibi.unex.es/dvorak/ES%20Dvorak.keylayout

It is pretty easy to make your own with Ukelele:

http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele